# Rails 5 API always return 200 OK, even if a rollback occurs. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a very strange problem. I'm working with Rails 5 and Devise to build json based REST api, but for every request, I get always `200 OK` even if a `Rollback` occurs. For example:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "user": { "email": "user@example.com", "password": "123457890" } }' -X POST http://api.test.com:3000/users/registration
```

It normally stores the User into database, but for example if I post again the same request, a `Rollback` is performed on databse because email is an index (**and is correct, is what I want...**) but the response is again `200 OK`.

Now, Devise controllers are overridden because I need to share them among different namespaces and modules, I override them as [Devise/Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) suggest, with the default behaviour of:

```
def method
    super
end
```

So, in a normal application, if some validation fails an error is returned to the User in the corresponding View, with the default controller (**that are the same of mine, nothing is changed!**). Why with "API only" application, each request seems is going always good? What am I forgetting?

Thanks to all.

**EDIT:** server output.

```
Started POST "users/registration" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>" [FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
    User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "user@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.3ms) ROLLBACK 
    Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant logs to this request?

Comment: Yes I edit the question, only for the error, the first transaction goes well!

Comment: What does the server return in the body?

Comment: The server is not treating the request as a JSON request. `Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*`. Either set the `default: { format: 'json' }` option in your routes or make sure you are sending an content type header with the request.

Comment: But using devise on an pure API app is a waste of time IMHO.

Comment: @spickermann body is empty, always. @max already done in `routes.rb` with the `default: {format: ':json'}` but nothing. So, I don't know, I'm just following your thought and switching to `devise_token_auth` gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

After 4 days of searching, I forgot the `respond_to :json` in my `application_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Content-Type and Accept headers in your request are configured correctly, eg. Accept -> application/json and Content-Type -> application/json.